# How to check if tree is a classification tree or regression tree

Tags: r, tree

I want to make a generic method for pruning my trees. The package that I'm using to make the trees is the standard c-ran "tree" package.

The method is dependent on the type of tree that I get.
I'm building my trees with the tree method like so

```
classification_tree_gini<- tree(Class~., train_df[,c(-1,-28)], split ="gini")
regression_tree_gini <- tree(UPDRS ~., train_df[,c(-1,-29)], split = "gini")
```

How can I retrieve the type of tree it is , code wise, so I can implement my method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned tree has stored values for predictions on the training data. You should be able to ask what the class is of these predictions.

```
class(regression_tree_gini$y)
[1] "numeric"
class(classification_tree_gini$y)
[1] "factor"
```